# How to print nested xml elements?

Tags: xpath, jasper-reports, xmldatasource

Sample xml:

```xml
<Root>
  <Customers>
    <Customer>
      <CompanyName>Great Lakes Food Market</CompanyName>
      <ContactName>Howard Snyder</ContactName>
      <ContactTitle>Marketing Manager</ContactTitle>
      <Phone>(503) 555-7555</Phone>
      <FullAddress>
        <Address>2732 Baker Blvd.</Address>
        <City>Eugene</City>
        <Region>OR</Region>
        <PostalCode>97403</PostalCode>
        <Country>USA</Country>
      </FullAddress>
    </Customer>
  </Customers>
</Root>
```

In the above xml, when I use "Customer" as the root node and xpath query as "/Root/Customers/Customer", I'm unable to print the child nodes of "FullAddress" and when I use "FullAddress" as the root node and the xpath query as "/Root/Customers/Customer/FullAddress", unable to print all the fields.

Kindly help me with the solution to print all the xml elements including the nested in a single report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct XPath query is

```
<queryString language="XPath">
    <![CDATA[/Root/Customers/Customer]]>
</queryString>
```

This include both of your nodes, to access the value is `FullAddress` node you should use XPath also in `fieldDescription` when you define your field, hence `Address` is accessed through `FullAddress/Address`

## Example

If the field declaration of `CompanyName` is

```
<field name="CompanyName" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[CompanyName]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

the field declaration of for example the `City` is

```
<field name="City" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[FullAddress/City]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!